# Typescript ESLint Indent rule doesn't indent multi-line object parameters correctly

Tags: typescript, eslint, indentation, typescript-eslint

I have a code block that looks like this:

```js
this.$api
  .get<AxiosResponse<Resource>>('/resources/', {
    params: {
      pageNumber: 1,
      pageLength: 10,
    }
  });
```

My typescript ESLint is autoformatting this codeblock like so:

```js
this.$api
  .get<AxiosResponse<Resource>>('/resources/', {
  params: {
    pageNumber: 1,
    pageLength: 10,
  }
});
```

This is not ideal and is imo very confusing. Similar behavior is referenced in an issue for `@typescript-eslint` [here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/455#issuecomment-530689637).

How can I update my ESLint config not to allow this?

Current ESLint config:

```js
/* eslint-env node */
require('@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution');

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/eslint-config-typescript/recommended',
  ],
  env: {
    'vue/setup-compiler-macros': true,
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['cypress/integration/**.spec.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
      extends: ['plugin:cypress/recommended'],
    },
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: [2, 'single', { avoidEscape: true }],
    indent: 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'off',
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': [
      'error',
      {
        singleline: {
          max: 1,
        },
        multiline: {
          max: 1,
        },
      },
    ],
    'vue/html-indent': [
      'error',
      2,
      {
        attribute: 1,
        baseIndent: 1,
        closeBracket: 0,
        alignAttributesVertically: false,
        ignores: [],
      },
    ],
    'vue/html-closing-bracket-newline': [
      'error',
      {
        singleline: 'never',
        multiline: 'always',
      },
    ],
    'vue/script-indent': [
      'error',
      2,
      {
        baseIndent: 0,
        switchCase: 1,
        ignores: [],
      },
    ],
    'vue/attributes-order': [
      'error',
      {
        order: [
          'DEFINITION',
          'LIST_RENDERING',
          'CONDITIONALS',
          'RENDER_MODIFIERS',
          'GLOBAL',
          ['UNIQUE', 'SLOT'],
          'TWO_WAY_BINDING',
          'OTHER_DIRECTIVES',
          'OTHER_ATTR',
          'EVENTS',
          'CONTENT'
        ],
        'alphabetical': false
      }
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/indent': [
      'error',
      2,
      {
        SwitchCase: 1,
        ObjectExpression: 1,
        MemberExpression: 1,
        CallExpression: {
          arguments: 1,
        },
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually discovered the answer to this but none of the relevant threads I found had an answer and they were also all closed issues so I couldn't leave any comments.

The solution is to tell Typescript ESLint to ignore the arguments in a call expression. Once I figured out this trick I also told it to ignore several other node types using the `ignoredNodes` property in the configuration for the `@typescript-eslint/indent` rule.

**Bear in mind that it is totally critical that you *also* disable the default `indent` rule.**

```js
/* eslint-env node */
require('@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution');

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/eslint-config-typescript/recommended',
  ],
  env: {
    'vue/setup-compiler-macros': true,
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['cypress/integration/**.spec.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
      extends: ['plugin:cypress/recommended'],
    },
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: [2, 'single', { avoidEscape: true }],
    indent: 'off',                                  // !!!! VERY IMPORTANT !!!!
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'off',
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': [
      'error',
      {
        singleline: {
          max: 1,
        },
        multiline: {
          max: 1,
        },
      },
    ],
    'vue/html-indent': [
      'error',
      2,
      {
        attribute: 1,
        baseIndent: 1,
        closeBracket: 0,
        alignAttributesVertically: false,
        ignores: [],
      },
    ],
    'vue/html-closing-bracket-newline': [
      'error',
      {
        singleline: 'never',
        multiline: 'always',
      },
    ],
    'vue/script-indent': [
      'error',
      2,
      {
        baseIndent: 0,
        switchCase: 1,
        ignores: [],
      },
    ],
    'vue/attributes-order': [
      'error',
      {
        order: [
          'DEFINITION',
          'LIST_RENDERING',
          'CONDITIONALS',
          'RENDER_MODIFIERS',
          'GLOBAL',
          ['UNIQUE', 'SLOT'],
          'TWO_WAY_BINDING',
          'OTHER_DIRECTIVES',
          'OTHER_ATTR',
          'EVENTS',
          'CONTENT'
        ],
        'alphabetical': false
      }
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/indent': [
      'error',
      2,
      {
        SwitchCase: 1,
        ObjectExpression: 1,
        MemberExpression: 1,
        CallExpression: {
          arguments: 1,
        },
        'ignoredNodes': [
          'PropertyDefinition[decorators]',
          'TSUnionType',
          'FunctionExpression[params]',
          'CallExpression[arguments]',              // !!!! VERY IMPORTANT !!!!
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
};
```